# Removing the entire subarray that contains a null value from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Having this kind of simply array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=
  array(5) {
    [0]= 
    string(61) "ramdom test"
    [1]= 
    string(7) "19"
    [2]= 
    string(7) "-99"
    [3]= 
    string(6) "ramdom test"
    [4]= 
    string(31) "ramdom test"
  }
  [1]= 
  array(5) {
    [0]= 
    string(61) "ramdom test 2"
    [1]= 
    string(7) "87"
    [2]= 
    string(7) "-42"
    [3]= 
    string(6) "NULL" // <--------------------------- THIS HAS A NULL VALUE
    [4]= 
    string(31) "ramdom test 2"
  }
  [2]= 
 array(5) {
    [0]= 
    string(61) "ramdom test 3"
    [1]= 
    string(7) "54"
    [2]= 
    string(7) "-67"
    [3]= 
    string(6) "ramdom test 3"
    [4]= 
    string(31) "ramdom test 3"
  }
 }
```

I want to remove the entire subarray that contains a `NULL` value, in this case, the key `[3]` of the `[1]` array has null, so how I want to remove the entire `[1]` array so I can get following desired output?

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=
  array(5) {
    [0]= 
    string(61) "ramdom test"
    [1]= 
    string(7) "19"
    [2]= 
    string(7) "-99"
    [3]= 
    string(6) "ramdom test"
    [4]= 
    string(31) "ramdom test"
  }
  [1]= 
 array(5) {
    [0]= 
    string(61) "ramdom test 3"
    [1]= 
    string(7) "54"
    [2]= 
    string(7) "-67"
    [3]= 
    string(6) "ramdom test 3"
    [4]= 
    string(31) "ramdom test 3"
  }
 }
```

I'm using:

```
$myArray = array_map('array_filter', $myArray);
```

But this removes me only the null item, not the entire subarray.

Comment: You need to implement an own, simple callback function that detects if a given array matches your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_filter function:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($v){
  return !in_array(null, $v, true);
});

# fix keys
$result = array_values($result);
```

More details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't reindex the keys, in the example given at the post, with the starting keys `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, your code would output `[0]`, `[2]`. To fix this you only have to add `$result  = array_values($result)` after the call (please, add it to the post). Thanks!